# NPM: Update all dependencies with scope

Tags: npm, scope, package.json

Is there a shortcut for updating all package dependencies that are of a particular scope.

For example is there are in the following `package.json` is there a quick way to update *only* those packages with an `@example` scope?:

```
…
dependencies: {
  alpha,
  bravo,
  @example/a,
  @example/b,
  @example/c,
  @example/d,
  @example/e,
  @example/f,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using yarn:

```
yarn upgrade --scope @example
```

Comment: This is interesting...I thought the yarn fork had been merged back into npm. Yarn still has features that npm does not??

Answer (score 11):

I wrote small tool for that. Run `npx update-by-scope @example` for Yarn project and `npx update-by-scope @example npm install` for Npm project

Comment: Looks useful, but please add some explanation to the README.

Answer (score 3):

I update dependencies using [the `npm-check-updates` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) -- just install it globally then run `ncu`.  By default it runs in "check" mode against all packages, but you can pass a command-line flag to have it write the newest version of each package to `package.json`.  It supports filtering so you could apply the updates only to a single scope, like `ncu '/@angular\/.*/'`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in `angular` project.
I use from the `script` section in `package.json`.

I set the `custom name` (e.g `update-scope`) as `key`, and set command(s) as `value`. follow this:

```
   "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "build": "node package-builder",
      "update-scope": "npm update @example/a && npm update @example/b && ..."
   }
```

then run `custom name` with this command:

```
npm run update-scope // `update-scope` is my custom name
```

finally, all of `my packages` in `my scope` was updated.

I hope is useful.

Comment: Isn't `npm update @example/a @example/b ...` better? Or `@example/{a,b,...}` if your terminal allows glob expansions.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this exact problem and package [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) did the trick seamlessly.

Type `npx npm-check -u` and select packages to upgrade and hit enter to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `yarn upgrade` was removed in recent versions of Yarn. Instead, use `yarn up '@scope/*'`, which will upgrade every package starting with `@scope/` in every package.json file to the latest version. See [these docs](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up). This also avoids having to install the upgrade plugin or using upgrade-interactive, which doesn't support pattern matching